# Rewrite external image URL from Apache web server (Htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite all image (all except webp) url from my server (Apache, wordpress) but most of my image is on CDN(digitalocean space)

so if my url is `https://halorumah.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/wp-content/***<many subfolder>***/filename.png` has to change to
`https://proxied-url/converttowebp/https://halorumah.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/wp-content/***<many subfolder>***/filename.png`

I have this rewrite rule on my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # Check if browser supports WebP
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
 # check if request is image jpg/jpeg/png
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jpg -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jpeg -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f
 # rewrite url to proxied url
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://proximg.halorumah.id/pximage/towebp/$1 [P]

</IfModule>
```

the rewrite rule above is not working.

the condition is to check whatever my server can serve webp version image or not, i need to change this rule so even if the image is on external server/cdn, if the image is not webp, i can rewrite that to proxied url.

[image]

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? CDN's don't usually process `.htaccess`/Apache config files? (Or are you expecting the `.htaccess` file to be processed when the CDN requests from the origin? Is that how the CDN is configured? But if it exists in the CDN and it's not expired then it's not going to request from the origin?) You appear to be assuming your CDN is configured as a _reverse proxy_, which I doubt that is the case. (?)

Comment: please check the question, i have add diagram for my use case
.htaccess file is in web server, not in CDN, i need to rewrite all image url to my proxy, after that my proxy is handle the access to CDN and optimize image before the image is display to end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will be better for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|png))$ https://proxied-url/converttowebp/https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [P]
```